# Undeclared identifier error when trying to compile

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I was trying to compile my contract for a project, but couldn't get past compilation because of an error.
Can somebody please help me?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later

pragma solidity 0.6.9;

import "./PriceAware.sol";
import { BlockContext } from "./utils/BlockContext.sol";
import "./PriceFeedL2.sol";

contract RedstonePriceFeed is PriceAware, BlockContext, PriceFeedL2   {
    function isSignerAuthorized(address _signer) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
        return _signer == 0x0C39486f770B26F5527BBBf942726537986Cd7eb;
        //redstone main provider
    }

    function updatePrice(bytes32 _priceFeedKey) external {
        requireKeyExisted(_priceFeedKey, true);

        uint256 price = getPriceFromMsg(_priceFeedKey);
        setLatestData(_priceFeedKey, price, _blockTimestamp());
    }
}
```

The error is as below:

```
src/RedstonePriceFeed.sol:19:9: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
        setLatestData(_priceFeedKey, price, _blockTimestamp());
        ^-----------^

Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

Comment: Where did you declare setLatestData function?

Comment: It's inherited from PriceFeedL2

Comment: Can you share that function?

Comment: ```function setLatestData(
        bytes32 _priceFeedKey,
        uint256 _price,
        uint256 _timestamp
    ) external {
        PriceData memory data = PriceData({ price: _price, timestamp: _timestamp });
        priceFeedMap[_priceFeedKey].priceData.push(data);

        emit PriceFeedDataSet(_priceFeedKey, _price, _timestamp);
    }
```

Comment: You are giving the uint256 for timestamp. What does _blocktimestamp() returns? Is it uint256 or something else? However you can simply use block.timestamp instead of giving function.

Comment: It's one and the same thing. I tried replacing it too, but the error still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the visibility of your `setLatestData` function to `internal` or `public`, or call it with the `this` keyword:

Like this:

```js
 function setLatestData(bytes32 _priceFeedKey, uint256 _price, uint256 _timestamp) public {
    }
```

Or:

```js
 function setLatestData(bytes32 _priceFeedKey, uint256 _price, uint256 _timestamp) internal {
    }
```

You will not be able to call it from your contract or from the same `PriceFeedL2` if it's declared as `external`, because external functions can only be called from outside of the contract

Another option is to call it with the `this` keyword because with this keyword it makes an `external` call:

```js
this.setLatestData(...);
```

Check docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/contracts.html#function-visibility

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Thanks a lot mate. I completely forgot about this.function() for external.

Answer (score 0):

I think `_blockTimestamp()` should be `block.timestamp` because I don't see where you got `_blockTimestamp()` from.

Comment: ```_blockTimestamp()``` is returning the same as ```block.timestamp```. And I tried replacing it too, that doesn't seem to be the issue in here